# Transfer of arguments in the application via cmd

Tags: windows

There is a [shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7g4T.png) that runs the exe file and pass parameter `NoCheckVersion`.

I am trying to run the same exe, but with the [cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xozrn.png). But the application is run as if it did not pass anything.

What could be the problem?

Comment: I'd advise you to go to the mentioned directory, and launch the program (with the argument) from there. In fact, when you verify the properties of your shortcut, what is the target directory?

Comment: I tried. The result is the same. Work directory is "D:\Runes of Magic".